# C# PictureBox and Timer don't work together

Tags: c#, timer, drawing, picturebox

so I am trying to make a simple game in C# using PictureBox for painting and timer for update functions, but what I noticed is that when I start painting on my picturebox my timer stops working.. I have no idea why..

Here is the picturebox code:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PicBox running!");
        if (this.MyGame.InGame)
        {
            this.pictureBox1.Refresh();
            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);               
            MyGame.CurrentMap.Draw(e.Graphics);
            //e.Graphics.Dispose(); <- if I uncomment this, then the whole programm just freezes
        }
    }
```

Here is the timer code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timer running!");
        if (this.MyGame.InGame)
        {
            MyGame.CurrentMap.Update();
            MyGame.UpdateTime();                
        }
    }
```

Here is a method called by MyGame.CurrentMap.Draw(e.Graphics); :

```
public void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        foreach(Planet item in Entities){
            item.Draw(g);
        }            
    }
```

Any help would be greately appreciated. I come from javascript, so I don't really know if I am doing something terribly wrong here.

Comment: Show how you initialise the timer please.

Comment: I think you need painting in another thread.

Comment: this.pictureBox1.Refresh(); should not be in pictureBox1_Paint, but in the end of timer1_Tick.

Comment: @Zoyd I love you man!! Works great now. I have been trying to figure this out for about 2 hours now.. Could you explain to me why it has to be at the end of the timer?

Comment: i agree with Gleb, If you have your timer and your private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) in the same thread, as soon as you paint in your picture box, you go to the pictureBox1_Paint method and you stop all the other methods, because your picturebox1_Paint is an event handler.. From what i can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a timer tick occurs, you want to repaint your PictureBox. To do this, you should make it so that the PictureBox receives a Paint event. This is what Refresh() does, so the call to this.pictureBox1.Refresh(); goes in the end of timer1_Tick.

It doesn't make sense for the Paint event to contain a call to Refresh, because this, in turn, generates a Paint event.